# Insert values in database from array table using ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

help me to insert data from array inputs from my table using ajax and php. I have the separate php file, but it is blank at the moment.

this is my current html + php code:

```
<form class='form-horizontal form-validate' id="form">
<?php
echo "<table id='example' class='table table-bordered'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Last Qtr Average time</th>
<th>Target time</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
<th>Category</th>
<th>last Qtr Average time</th>
<th>Target time</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>";
$get_category_query = "select * from daily_checklist_category order by category asc";
$get_category_result = mysql_query($get_category_query) or die(mysql_error());
while($count_rows = mysql_fetch_row($get_category_result)){
echo'<tr>';
echo'<td>'.$count_rows[1].'</td>';
echo'<td id="fucktime[]">'.$count_rows[2].'</td>';
echo'<td><input type="text" value="'.$count_rows[3].'" id="cat_rows[]"/></td>';
echo'</tr>';                                    
}
echo "</tbody>

</table>";
?>
<div class="form-actions">
<input type="submit" id="finish" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</div>
```

and this is my ajax :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#form').ajaxForm(function(){
    //$("#loading").fadeIn();

    var catRows = $('#cat_rows[]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        url: 'pages/scripts/insert_daily_checklist_category.php',
        cache: false,
        success:function(data){
            alert('Daily Checklist Categories are now updated.');
        }
    });
  });

});
```

need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue in your code is that, you are not using name field in input field:

```
<input type="text" value="'.$count_rows[3].'" id="cat_rows[]"/>
```

This Should be:

```
<input type="text" name="cat_rows[]" value="'.$count_rows[3].'" id="cat_rows"/>
```

**In jQuery:**

You need to get this value as:

```
var catRows = $('#cat_rows').val();
```

**Side note:**

I am assuming you are using  closing tag in your original file.

Also use **mysqli_** or **PDO** becuase **mysql_** extension is deprecated and not available in PHP 7.

Comment: thanks for that. i tested that in ajax and json, tried to output it, but it alerts, "undefined" instead of its value.

Comment: Undefine in ajax success @pao

Comment: yes. how can i get atleast 1 row to be outputed in my ajax success? using json?

Comment: @pao if u r sendind response in ajax than use datatype in ajax param **dataType:"json",**

Comment: this is my  ajax code:

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#form').ajaxForm(function(){
  //$("#loading").fadeIn();
 
  var catRows = $('#cat_rows').val();
  $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   data: {'cat_rows':catRows},
   url: 'pages/scripts/insert_daily_checklist_category.php',
   cache: false,
   dataType: 'json',
   success:function(data){
    alert(data.catrows);
    //alert('Daily Checklist Categories are now updated.');
   }
  });
 });

});

Comment: <?php
include("../../jireh.class.php");

$cat_target = $_GET['cat_rows'];

$obj = array();

$obj['catrows'] = $cat_target;

echo json_encode($obj);

?>

and this is my php code

Comment: @pao instead of alert(data.catrows); use console.log(data.catrows); because its an array chk in console

Comment: @pao also add form method get in form tag

Comment: @pao and what r u getting in print_r($_GET); in php file

Answer (score 0):

First add the name attribute into your input form element like this.

```
echo '<td><input type="text" name="cat_rows[]" value="'.$count_rows[3].'" id="cat_rows_'.$count_rows[3].'"/></td>';
```

And your are already using **ajaxForm** jquery so there is no need of any another write ajax statement into callback. Your **ajaxForm** jquery would be like this.

**jQuery Example-**

```
// bind form using 'ajaxForm' 
$('#form').ajaxForm({
  url: 'pages/scripts/insert_daily_checklist_category.php',
  beforeSubmit: function(formData, jqForm, options) {
    // write code here like loader if needed
  },
  success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
    // write code for response handling
  }
});
```

Comment: how i do retrieve array input rows using php? 

       var catRows = $('#cat_rows').val();

this is my variable in ajax call to get values from my array input boxes, but it seems that its getting nothing.

Comment: @Pao, Why are you doing this, I can't understand? There is no need of this, you can retrieve form input value at php server just using $_REQUEST['cat_rows'] and this will return an array.

Comment: its ok now, thanks for the advices sir. i used $('#form').serialize() instead of var catRows = $('#cat_rows').val(). and i used while loop and if else statement inside it to update my database rows from my array inputs.